# Why are there $5$ pairs of congruent triangles?

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

I have the following picture:

[image: $AG = BF$]

I only found $4$ pairs of congruent triangles: {$\triangle ACO$, $\triangle ODB$}; {$\triangle CFE$, $\triangle EDG$}; {$\triangle ODF$, $\triangle COG$}; {$\triangle AOC$, $\triangle CFE$}.

However, the answer said there should be $5$.

Where's the fifth pair of congruent triangles?

Answer (score 1):

This answer shows that if we are *not* allowed to draw extra lines, then there are **only four** pairs of congruent triangles.

(If we are allowed to draw extra lines, the number of such pairs is more than four since we have $\triangle{OAF}\equiv\triangle{OBG}$.)

$\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image]

Since we are not allowed to draw extra lines, we have only eight triangles to consider :

$$\triangle{ACO},\quad \triangle{AGO},\quad\triangle{DEG},\quad\triangle{BDO}$$
$$\triangle{BFO},\quad\triangle{DFO},\quad\triangle{CEF},\quad\triangle{CGO}$$

Considering only angles, there are only eight candidates for congruent pairs :

$$(\triangle{ACO},\triangle{GDE}),\quad (\triangle{ACO},\triangle{BDO}),\quad (\triangle{ACO},\triangle{FCE}),\quad (\triangle{AGO},\triangle{BFO})$$
$$(\triangle{GDE},\triangle{BDO}),\quad (\triangle{GDE},\triangle{FCE}),\quad (\triangle{BDO},\triangle{FCE}),\quad (\triangle{DFO},\triangle{CGO})$$

Now, we have
$$\triangle{ACO}\equiv \triangle{BDO},\quad \triangle{GDE}\equiv\triangle{FCE},\quad \triangle{DFO}\equiv\triangle{CGO},\quad\triangle{AGO}\equiv\triangle{BFO}$$

However, we have
$$\triangle{ACO}\not\equiv\triangle{GDE},\quad \triangle{ACO}\not\equiv\triangle{FCE},\quad \triangle{GDE}\not\equiv\triangle{BDO},\quad \triangle{BDO}\not\equiv\triangle{FCE}$$
since 
$$AO\not=GE,\quad AC\not=FC,\quad DG\not=DB,\quad BO\not=FE$$
respectively.

Comment: Instead of $OAF≡OBG$, how about $OCG≡ODF$?

Comment: @TakahiroWaki: The OP has already noticed $\triangle{ODF}\equiv \triangle{OCG}$. (see the first sentence in my answer.)

Comment: @mathlove you are not allowed to draw extra lines.

Comment: @Kw08: Then, there are only four pairs of congruent triangles. See the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The pair AOG and FOB are built out of triangles you have as congruent, so they are congruent.